# Plotting Whether Measured Locations for Components are Within Spec - follow-up

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, gui, tkinter

I've made this GUI program for my workplace that checks whether measured coordinates on machined components are within spec.

It takes in specified coordinates, tolerance and measured coordinates and uses Pythagoras to check whether the tolerance has been exceeded.

It then plots the measured point relative to the 'true point' on a tkinter canvas which can be scaled up and down with the slider widget (points are scaled proportionally - this was the challenging bit for me). The tolerance value determines the radius of the circle shown below.

[image]

I've ran the program through pylint and am now getting good results (9.72). I'm now hoping for a bit of feedback on anything I could have done better. I was also trying to work to OOP ideas. Any comments about these or other areas would be much appreciated.

The code posted here is a revision of that posted in: [Plotting Whether Measured Locations for Components are Within Spec](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234976/plotting-whether-measured-locations-for-components-are-within-spec)

```py
"""Validates points against engineering drawing according to specified tolerance"""
from tkinter import  Tk, Label, Entry, GROOVE, Button, IntVar, Canvas, Scale, Checkbutton, DoubleVar, Widget, Variable
import math

class TruePosition:
    """Populates Tk window object with widgets"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('True Position Validator')

        self.h_cor = DoubleVar()
        self.k_cor = DoubleVar()
        self.tol_cor = DoubleVar()
        self.x_cor = DoubleVar()
        self.y_cor = DoubleVar()
        self.checkvar = IntVar()
        self.entries = []

        self.heading('True Point Location Details')
        self.row('Point Loc:', self.h_cor, ',', self.k_cor)
        self.row('Tolerance:', self.tol_cor)

        self.heading('Measured Point Location Details')
        self.row('Point Loc:', self.x_cor, ',', self.y_cor)
        btn = Button(master, text='Submit', font=('Technic', 10),
                              command=lambda: self.submit_action())

        self.row(None, None, None, btn)

        self.labelout = self.row("")[0]
        self.labelout.grid(columnspan = 4)

        self.display_canvas = Canvas(master, bg='white', border=2, highlightthickness=1,
                                     highlightbackground='black')
        self.display_canvas.grid(row=8, columnspan=4, sticky='s')


        bclear = Button(master, text='Clear', font=('Technic', 10),
                        command=lambda: self.clearcrosses())

        retain = Checkbutton(master, text='Retain plots', variable=self.checkvar,
                             command=lambda: self.box_check())

        self.row(retain, None, None, bclear)[1].grid(sticky = 'n')

        self.slider = Scale(master, orient='horizontal', from_=0, to=100,
                            command=lambda factor: self.scalar(factor=float(factor)))
        self.slider.set(100)

        self.slider.grid(row=9, columnspan=4)

        self.master.bind("<Return>", lambda t: self.submit_action())

        self.canvas_width = self.display_canvas.winfo_reqwidth()
        self.canvas_height = self.display_canvas.winfo_reqheight()

# Running Variables

        self.cross = False

        self.stored_points = []
        self.line_length = 10
        self.h_val = None
        self.k_val = None
        self.tol_val = DoubleVar()
        self.x_val = None
        self.y_val = None

        self.real = None
        self.clearance = None
        self.radius = DoubleVar()

        self.linea_x1 = None
        self.linea_x2 = None
        self.linea_y = None
        self.lineb_y1 = None
        self.lineb_y2 = None
        self.lineb_x = None

        self.linea = None
        self.lineb = None

        self.meas_point(self.canvas_width/2, self.canvas_height/2)
        self.create_points()

        self.truecircle = self.display_canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 0, 0, outline='black', dash=(4, 5))

# Functions

    def heading(self, title):
        _, rows = self.master.grid_size()
        label = Label(self.master, text=title, font=('Technic', 14))
        label.grid(row=rows, columnspan=4, sticky='w')

    def row(self, *fields):
        _, rows = self.master.grid_size()
        widgets = [] # resets list every time, so when I pass in the one label item, it is the only widget in the list

        for col, field in enumerate(fields):
            widget = None
            if isinstance(field, str):
                widget = Label(self.master, text=field, font=('Technic', 14))
            elif isinstance(field, Variable):
                widget = Entry(self.master, textvar=field, relief=GROOVE)
                self.entries.append(field)
            elif isinstance(field, Widget):
                widget = field

            if widget:
                widget.grid(row=rows, column=col, sticky ='w')
                widgets.append(widget)

        return widgets

    def box_check(self):
        """Acknowledges box check & stores existing point if switching from-non retention mode"""
        if self.checkvar.get() == 1 and self.cross:
            self.store_points()
        elif self.checkvar.get() == 0:
            self.clearcrosses()

        print('ran box_check\n')

    def submit_action(self):
        """Accepts user input and runs subsequent functions"""
        try:
            self.calctrue()
            self.showtrue()
            self.meas_point(self.x_val, self.y_val, 'cross')
            if not self.cross or self.checkvar.get() == 1:
                self.create_points('cross')
                self.cross = True
                if self.checkvar.get() == 1:
                    self.store_points()
                else:
                    pass
            elif self.cross:
                self.move_points(self.linea, self.lineb)
        except ValueError: #  Accounts for accidental pressing of submit before all data is entered
            self.labelout.config(fg='black')
            self.labelout['text'] = 'ValueError : Make sure all fields have been completed.'

        except ZeroDivisionError: #  Accounts for accidental pressing of submit before all data is entered
            self.labelout.config(fg='black')
            self.labelout['text'] = 'ValueError : Make sure all fields have been completed.'

        print('ran submit_action()\n')

    def scalar(self, factor):
        """Runs logic that changes circle size in response to
        slider and remeasures & shifts existing points"""
        self.getplot_circ(factor)
        if self.checkvar.get() == 0 and self.cross:
            self.meas_point(self.x_val, self.y_val, 'cross')
            self.move_points(self.linea, self.lineb)
        elif self.checkvar.get() == 1 and self.cross:
            for pnt0, pnt1 in self.stored_points:
                self.meas_point(*pnt1, 'cross')
                self.move_points(*pnt0)
        elif not self.cross:
            pass

        print('ran scalar\n')

    def getplot_circ(self, factor):
        """Changes circle size"""
        factor = 192 - (factor*1.27)

        self.radius = (self.canvas_width/2)- factor

        c1_x = (self.canvas_width/2) - self.radius
        c1_y = (self.canvas_height/2) - self.radius
        c2_x = (self.canvas_width/2) + self.radius
        c2_y = (self.canvas_height/2) + self.radius

        self.display_canvas.coords(self.truecircle, c1_x, c1_y, c2_x, c2_y)

        print('ran getplot_circ()')

    def calctrue(self):
        """Determines if point is within spec"""
        self.h_val = self.h_cor.get()
        self.k_val = self.k_cor.get()
        self.tol_val = self.tol_cor.get()
        self.x_val = self.x_cor.get()
        self.y_val = self.y_cor.get()

        self.real = math.hypot(self.x_val - self.h_val, self.y_val - self.k_val)
        self.clearance = self.tol_val - self.real

        print('ran calctrue()')

    def showtrue(self):
        """Provides non-graphical feedback about results of calctrue"""
        if self.tol_val >= self.real:
            self.labelout.config(fg='green')
            self.labelout['text'] = f'Position is within spec by {round(self.clearance, 4)}'
            self.display_canvas.itemconfig(self.truecircle, outline='green')
        elif self.tol_val < self.real:
            self.labelout.config(fg='red')
            self.labelout['text'] = f'Position is outwith spec by {round(abs(self.clearance), 4)}'
            self.display_canvas.itemconfig(self.truecircle, outline='red')

    def meas_point(self, loc_x, loc_y, tag='all'):
        """defines new point in terms of current circle & canvas geometry"""
        pix_x = 5
        if tag == 'all':
            pix_x = loc_x
            pix_y = loc_y
        elif tag == 'cross':
            scale = self.radius/self.tol_val
            print('scale')
            pix_x = (scale * (loc_x-self.h_val)) + self.canvas_width/2
            pix_y = (-scale * (loc_y-self.k_val)) + self.canvas_height/2

        self.linea_x1 = (pix_x - (self.line_length/2))
        self.linea_x2 = (pix_x + (self.line_length/2))
        self.linea_y = (pix_y)

        self.lineb_y1 = (pix_y - (self.line_length/2))
        self.lineb_y2 = (pix_y + (self.line_length/2))
        self.lineb_x = (pix_x)

        print('ran meas_point')

    def create_points(self, tag='all'):
        """Plots new cross point"""
        self.linea = self.display_canvas.create_line(self.linea_x1, self.linea_y,
                                                     self.linea_x2, self.linea_y, tag=tag)
        self.lineb = self.display_canvas.create_line(self.lineb_x, self.lineb_y1,
                                                     self.lineb_x, self.lineb_y2, tag=tag)
        print('ran create_points()')

    def move_points(self, linea, lineb):
        """Shifts cross point to measured locations"""
        self.display_canvas.coords(linea, self.linea_x1, self.linea_y,
                                   self.linea_x2, self.linea_y)
        self.display_canvas.coords(lineb, self.lineb_x, self.lineb_y1,
                                   self.lineb_x, self.lineb_y2)

        print('ran move_points()')

    def store_points(self):
        """stores points for rescaling if slider is used"""
        self.stored_points.append(((self.linea, self.lineb), (self.x_val, self.y_val)))

        print('ran store_points()')

    def clearcrosses(self):
        """deletes all user input"""
        for item in self.display_canvas.find_withtag('cross'):
            self.display_canvas.delete(item)
        self.labelout['text'] = ''
        self.display_canvas.itemconfig(self.truecircle, outline='black')
        self.cross = False
        self.stored_points = []

        for instance in self.entries:
            instance.set('')

        print('ran clearcrosses()\n')

ROOT = Tk()
MYAPP = TruePosition(ROOT)

ROOT.mainloop()
```